# Exception we have null reference object but the radio button is initialized

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been blocked for 2 days, I have an exception on a radio button for a change of language of the application, activity stop with nullPointerException on a null objet reference,

"NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.RadioGroup$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference"

strings file xml are ok, do you see something that I do not see? here is the code :

```
public class ArtistActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

TextView name;
ImageView img;
TextView music;
String title;
String musicArtist;
MaterialButton btnPlay;
MaterialButton btnStop;
TextView titleMusicArtist;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
RadioGroup rdioGrp;

// information artist
String imgUrl = "https://st3.depositphotos.com/1008939/12603/i/950/depositphotos_126032722-stock-photo-roaring-singing-woman.jpg";
String musicUrl = "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-4.mp3";
String siteUrl = "https://sites.google.com/view/bestrecord/accueil?authuser=1";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_artist);


    // button music, playlist and new playlist
    LinearLayout linearPlaylist = findViewById(R.id.linearPlaylist);
    LinearLayout linearNewPlaylist = findViewById(R.id.linearNewPlaylist);
    LinearLayout linearMusic = findViewById(R.id.linearMusic);
    linearPlaylist.setOnClickListener(this);
    linearNewPlaylist.setOnClickListener(this);
    linearMusic.setOnClickListener(this);
    linearMusic.setTag(0);
    linearPlaylist.setTag(1);
    linearNewPlaylist.setTag(2);

    // button play
    btnPlay = findViewById(R.id.btn_play_music_artist);
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPlay.setTag(3);

    // button stop
    btnStop = findViewById(R.id.btn_stop_music_artist);
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnStop.setTag(4);

    // textView title Music
    titleMusicArtist = findViewById(R.id.txtLastMusicPlayed);

    // display artist information
    name = findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitleArtist);
    img = findViewById(R.id.imageArtist);
    music = findViewById(R.id.txtViewMusicArtist);


    // image artiste
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    try {
        InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imgUrl).openStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // name and song title artist
    Scrape scrapeTitle = new Scrape();
    scrapeTitle.execute();


    // prepare music artist
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(musicUrl);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // language configuration
    init();

}



// scrape information artist
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class Scrape extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

    Document document = null;
    try {
        // Connect to the website
        document = Jsoup.connect(siteUrl).get();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // take name artist
    assert document != null;
    List<String> e = document.getElementsByClass(" jgG6ef").eachText();
    title = e.get(0)+" "+e.get(1);
    name.setText(title);

    // take song title artist
    List<String> ee = document.getElementsByAttributeValue("id","h.s0qhywz0cts2").eachText();
    musicArtist = ee.get(0);
    music.setText(musicArtist);
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) { }
}

// create menu application
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_mainactivity, menu);
    return true;
}

// menu buttons music / playlist / new playlist
public void onClick(View v) {
    int btnInt = ( int ) v.getTag();

    // button music clicked
    if ( btnInt == 0 ) {
        // go to page music
        Intent musicIntent = new Intent(ArtistActivity.this, MainActivity.class );
        startActivity( musicIntent );

    // button playlist clicked
    } else if ( btnInt == 1 ) {
        // go to page playlist
        Intent PlaylistIntent = new Intent(ArtistActivity.this, PlaylistActivity.class );
        startActivity( PlaylistIntent );

    // button new playlist clicked
    }else if ( btnInt == 2 ) {
        // go to page new playlist
        Intent newPlaylistIntent = new Intent(ArtistActivity.this, NewPlaylistActivity.class );
        startActivity( newPlaylistIntent );
    }
    // end menu button


    // button play/pause
    else if( btnInt == 3) {
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            btnPlay.setIconResource(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_arrow_24);
        } else if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) btnPlay.setIconResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
        }
    }
    // button stop
    else if( btnInt == 4) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(musicUrl);
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

// menu hamburger, items clicked
@SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.artiste:
            Toast.makeText(ArtistActivity.this, item.getTitle().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

        case R.id.site_officiel:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("https://sites.google.com/view/bestrecord/accueil?authuser=1"));
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        case R.id.contact:
            Intent contactIntent = new Intent(ArtistActivity.this, ContactBestRecord.class );
            startActivity( contactIntent );
            break;

        case R.id.langue:
            AlertDialog.Builder alertLang = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
            alertLang.setView( R.layout.layout_test )
                    .create()
                    .show();
            break;

        case R.id.about:
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
            alert.setView( R.layout.about_us )
                    .create()
                    .show();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
// end menu



// change language
public void init() {
    rdioGrp = findViewById(R.id.rdioGrpLang);
    rdioGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            if (rb!=null){
                switch(checkedId) {
                    case R.id.radioBtnFr:
                        changeLang("fr");
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioBtnEn:
                        changeLang("en");
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioBtnIt:
                        changeLang("it-rIT");
                        break;

                    default:
                        changeLang("fr");
                }

            }
        }
    });

}

// method to change language
public void changeLang(String l) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(l);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    recreate();
}
}
```

the layout call in dialBox layout "test" :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/border_layout_about_us"
android:padding="@dimen/dim_15">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/chooseLanguage"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/dim_20"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:ignore="SpUsage"
    android:id="@+id/txtLangue"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtLangue"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    >


    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dim_10"
        android:id="@+id/rdioGrpLang"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioBtnFr"
            android:checked="true"
            android:buttonTint="@color/white"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/langueFr">
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioBtnEn"
            android:text="@string/langueEn"
            android:buttonTint="@color/white"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dim_10"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dim_10">
        </RadioButton>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/radioBtnIt"
            android:buttonTint="@color/white"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="@string/langueIt">
        </RadioButton>

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post complete code and error logcat.

Comment: ok just a moment to post

Comment: have you debugged your code?

Comment: This has returned `null`: `rdioGrp = findViewById(R.id.rdioGrpLang);`. In `onCreate()` you need to set the correct layout with `setContentView()` and any `findViewById()` should be after it and not before. so there's something to check.

Comment: ok all code of activity is post

Comment: no Stultuske, i try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete -//language configuration- In Your Code And

Edit The onOptionsItemSelected method as follows:

```
@SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    ....
    ....
    case R.id.langue:
    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder( this ).setView( R.layout.choose_language).create();
    alert.show();
    rdioGrp = alert.findViewById(R.id.rdioGrpLang);
    setRadioListener();
        break;

    ....
    ....
} // End onOptionsItemSelected Mehtod


private void setRadioListener() {

    rdioGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) 
group.findViewById(checkedId);
            if (rb!=null){
                switch(checkedId) {
                    case R.id.radioBtnFr:
                        changeLang("fr");
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioBtnEn:
                        changeLang("en");
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioBtnIt:
                        changeLang("it-rIT");
                        break;

                    default:
                        app.l("iiii");
                }

            }
        }
    });
}

public void changeLang(String l) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(l);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    recreate();
}
```

Comment: With findViewById in this class you will only have access to the views defined in activity_artist

Comment: the radio button is in a layout, and the layout is call in menu hamberger in a dilogBox, maybe it is the probleme ?

Comment: The null error means that the rdioGrp object is not set.
If you have five activities and five layout
  A activity only has access to its internal components(mean only at setContentView(R.layout.layout1) 
If of activity 1 you call radiaogroup in layout 2, it will get a null error

Comment: yes i understand (i think), but i have try this just in this activity for testing, later when the code is ok i move in another class

Comment: i create a new layout just for this for testing your solution, thx u

Comment: i have try, not this, the activity stop when i click in change_language :

Comment: case R.id.langue:
                AlertDialog.Builder alertLang = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
                alertLang.setView( R.layout.layout_test )
                        .create()
                        .show();
                break;

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.card, PID: 9839
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.card/com.example.card.Activity.ArtistActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.RadioGroup$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: NullPointerException /// on a null object reference

Comment: Does the alertdialog you created have a separate class? Or anonymous class

Comment: no, the dialBox is created in the activity

Comment: and she take the layout in my directory res/layout

Comment: the dialBox and layout whithout the code listener works

Comment: all activity and class works without the code listener of language

Comment: Please write the alertDialog code. You must set radioButton listener from  alrtDialog.

Comment: ok, the code is in menu hamberger in the post code, i try your solution thx nima

Comment: Oh sorry I did not notice

Comment: case R.id.langue:
                init();
                AlertDialog.Builder alertLang = new AlertDialog.Builder( this );
                alertLang.setView( R.layout.layout_test )
                        .create()
                        .show();
                break;

Comment: there is the same probleme

Comment: i test more with your solution

Comment: Finding the solution I am now editing the class

Comment: i go to try in a new project in empty activity, if i solve i post, thx you all for your help

Comment: Code Edited .please try Up Code

Comment: it's ok, it's in the post, when comment all code language, all works

Comment: i try in the new activity

Comment: i have the init() in the onCreate, i have try in case language in menu

Comment: I edited the code. Please try the new code I wrote

Comment: choose_language is not related to ArtistActivity.
With findViewById in ArtistActivity, you can only access the views you defined in R.layout.activity_artist, and if the view is not in activity_artist, it will give a null error

Comment: no problem
Incidentally, I was very happy to be able to solve your problem

Comment: Although your language is not English, thank God you live in France.
We live in Iran and almost all companies have blocked our access.
Even in Android Studio, we can not sign
We can not place ads on the application because Google has closed our package.
Even if we could, the world's banks would boycott us and companies could not pay us.
Being born in a country other than Iran is a blessing especially for a programmer :)

Comment: I did not know that iran was blocked, ouch, anyway thank you for your help, 2 days that I was blocked, while developing this application, I am learning android :)